# Make COUNTIFS ignore blank cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to use a COUNTIFS formula to calculate how many installs are done. This is done by searching through a large table containing many blank cells. When using the following formula, I receive a `#VALUE!` error because Excel sees the blank cells as `0`s and gets confused trying to count strings and integers:

```
=COUNTIFS(B10:B152,"Installs",D10:N152,"Done")
```

The range D10:N152 contains blanks and is causing the error.

Can I make Excel ignore those blanks or see them as strings instead of integers?

Comment: As pnuts points out, your error has nothing to do with blank cells, but rather as your ranges are not of an equal dimension. I'm curious, however: what should the count be if "Done" occurs many times within the same row? Perhaps post a small dataset to aid clarification.

Comment: There will only be one "Done" per row. Each column represents 1 week and so once it is marked "Done" we leave the rest of the row blank. We did it this way to avoid the exact concern you bring up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842):

> Important   Each additional range must have the same number of rows and columns as the criteria_range1 argument. The ranges do not have to be adjacent to each other.

Maybe add a helper column, say `O` with:

```
=IF(MATCH("Done",D10:N10,0)>=1,"Done","")
```

copied down to suit and then:

```
=COUNTIFS(B10:B152,"Installs",O10:O152,"Done")
```

---

Now we know only one `Done` per row (and assuming `Done` is on its own in a cell) then a helper column with say:

```
=COUNTIF(D10:N10,"Done")
```

would be a shorter formula than `=IF(MATCH("Done",D10:N10,0)>=1,"Done","")` and also allow a shorter formula than `=COUNTIFS(B10:B152,"Installs",O10:O152,"Done")` for the counting, say:

```
=SUM(O:O)
```

instead (assuming the rest of ColumnO is blank or text, otherwise `=SUM(O10:O152`).

However I aimed for a formula as similar as possible to that used by OP, for which the helper column needed to be populated with `Done` also. At the time I was allowing for the possibility there might be more than one `Done` per row.

As pointed out in a comment, the helper column might have been populated with fewer keystrokes than `=IF(MATCH("Done",D10:N10,0)>=1,"Done","")`, if only by excluding the result for failure of the test, say `=IF(MATCH("Done",D10:N10,0)>=1,"Done")` since MATCH never ‘fails’ – rather it returns `#N/A` where no match is found, which is good enough for a COUNTIF function since that does not count `#N/A`s when the criterion is `Done`.

Comment: Can I suggest putting =IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("done",D10:N10,0)),"done","")  i.e. without the 0 it could match a phrase like "awaiting completion"

Comment: While I was not able to get that formula to do exactly what I wanted, your explanation was much appreciated. I used that knowledge to calculate totals through several separate countifs formulas. Thanks.

Comment: @pnuts Have you checked your MATCH construction? The value_if_value clause, i.e. "", will never be returned as desired.

Comment: Then you obviously still need more, because you can't even generate a FALSE result from that construction! Ever!

Comment: I disagree. Errors should be accounted for at source, not left to linger in the sheet. It's more the point that you're using a redundant IF clause with MATCH, i.e. evaluating its result as to whether it's >=1. But an error (which is precisely what MATCH may return) will neither be considered TRUE nor FALSE by that construction, but merely an error. This is why it's almost universal to pass MATCH to ISNUMBER, which can handle errors.

Comment: No. I'm just saying that your construction makes perfect sense if you change the comparison from >=1 to ISNUMBER: IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Done",D10:N10,0)),"Done","").

Comment: @pnuts From your proficiency on this site, I would have to disagree with (a). As for (b), no comment! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this `FormulaArray`:

```
=SUM(($B$10:$B$152="Installs")*($D$10:$N$152="Done"))
```